# AngularJS State routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three states - app, app.devices, app.devices.device.
App and app.devices states are working, but app.devices.device isn't.

Code:
http://pastebin.com/r1kYuExp
http://pastebin.com/uEcV7Chv

Comment: What do you mean with isn't working? What is the outcome? Do you see the View when you call yourdomain.com/device ?

Comment: <a data-ui-sref="app.devices.device" type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Details</a>

Comment: I have an a element that should redirect me to a template in the content div.

Comment: I fixed it, I shouldn't have used nested states for what I wanted to do.

Comment: I have one more problem, when I format the table with the button it doesn't work, but when I do it by hand (just insert the html in the template) it works. Code: http://pastebin.com/ZRVYDs35

Answer (score 0):

This is your code

```
  module.config(function ($stateProvider, $couchPotatoProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('app.devices', {
                views: {"content": {"templateUrl": "app/devices/devices.tpl.html"}},
                'url': '/devices',
                controller: 'DevicesCtrl',
                data: {title: 'Devices'},
                resolve: {
                    deps: $couchPotatoProvider.resolveDependencies([
                        'devices/DevicesCtrl'
                    ])
                }
            }
        ).state('app.devices.device', {
            'views': {'content': {"templateUrl": "app/devices/device.tpl.html"}},
            'url': '/device'
        });
    });
```

You have not define controller for `app.devices.device`, So that's not working Please define your controller

```
.state('app.devices.device', {
                'views': {'content': {"templateUrl": "app/devices/device.tpl.html"}},
                'url': '/device',
                 controller: 'YourController',
            });
```

Comment: I don't think it's required to define the controller.